# How can I programmatically abort an operation that is taking too long?

Tags: abort

I have a function `f`, over whose source code I have no control. Is there a way for me to decorate `f` so that if the evaluation time on an input exceeds, say, five seconds, the returned value is something like `Missing["EvaluationThresholdReached"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
TimeConstrained[f[whatever],5,Missing["EvaluationThresholdReached"]]
```

?

Comment: Excellent. I didn't know about this function. Thank you.